# SQL update from one Databse to another based on a Title match

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I just finished migrating my WordPress database, everything went right.

Until I realise that I got a serious issue the posts ID changed after this processes

And I’m using the posts ID on my URLs and I want to keep using it to don’t lose
my old links.

I still have both databases (old & new) and I want to know how I can update the ID from old one to the new one matching the title?

Something like:

```
Update newbase table ID from oldbase table id where oldbase title = newbase title
```

:p something like that :d

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating the pseudo-code into SQL should do the trick:

```
UPDATE newdb.tablename AS n
INNER JOIN olddb.tablename AS o ON n.title=o.title
SET n.id=o.id;
```

**Caveat**

You might run into duplicate id values, so you might want to move them first

```
SELECT @oldmax:=MAX(id) FROM olddb.tablename;
SELECT @newmax:=MAX(id) FROM newdb.tablename;
UPDATE newdb.tablename SET id=id+@oldmax+@newmax;
```

Comment: I tried the query seems working but it’s taking me 1 day and still running. Is it normal? By the way I have huge database each one have like 90.000 entry.

Comment: Did you forget the index on one of the title columns?

Comment: How can i do this (indexing) one of the title columns

Comment: After indexing post_title columns and disabling primary and auto increment from ID columns’ due to duplicate error. It WORKED. Thanks for the help